# create a JSON file and save into disk

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6, flexjson

how to create a JSON file for any object and save it on disk. after some days retrieve it back?

Answer (score 1):

To write to a shared object

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("mySharedObject");
so.data.storedJSON = myJSON;
so.flush();
```

To retrieve it back elsewhere

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("mySharedObject");
myJSON = so.data.storedJSON;
```

convert to ByteArray

save

read a this documentation: [registerClassAlias](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias%28%29)

```
registerClassAlias("com.myDomain", MyClass);
var myClass:MyClass = new MyClass();
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeObject(myClass);
so.data.byteArray = ba;
ba.position = 0;
```

read

```
myClass = so.data.byteArray.readObject();
```

Comment: but cookies are not store permanently.how save in database in some UiObject and retrieve it back?

Comment: Ok, I modified. method using a SharedObject. check out please.

Comment: Is not well understood. A little more clearly, let us know. you want save UIComponets?

Comment: so.data.object form not able cast in UIform for UICOmponents.

Comment: i asked a question few days ago and implement that but i was not able to object in same class..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135313/save-application-state-in-diagram-application

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24177/discussion-between-dev-and-bitmapdata-com)

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedObjects. Read up on them [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html).

Comment: i used sharedOject class but retrieve data from amf file in row form. i was not able to cast this object into DisplayObjects.

Comment: You won't be able to `JSON.serialize()` a DisplayObject, it's plain normal. They contain too much links that make you lose data integrity if you save and then load a DisplayObject. So, you have another problem, the solution is [IExternalizable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html), it requires a lot of code but lets you save your entire data structure and then restore it object by object.